# Combining paths using os.path.join

Tags: python, python-3.4, os.path

I was wondering how you correctly use os.path. Basically what I'm trying to do is ask the user for a directory and after that, they type a letter (`N` in this case), and then a filename in the directory and it will combine the directory with the file.

For example:

```
C:\Desktop
```

and

```
N hello
```

The final result produced would be C:\Desktop\hello.

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
```

':
        directory = input()
        search_files()
        directory1=search_characteristics(directory)
        #print(directory1)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what your overall code is supposed to do, how it is currently failing, and what exactly you expect it to do that is not behaving as you think it should. This helps narrow down the troubleshooting to provide a quicker, better answer.

Comment: @idjaw I'm slowly working on the overall code, but what N is supposed to do is 
If the second line of the input begins with the letter N, the search will be for files whose names exactly match a particular name. The N will be followed by space; after the space, the rest of the line will indicate the name of the files to be searched for. 

Right now, when I try to combine the paths, say `C:\Desktop` with a hello.txt in desktop, it would still show the thing like `C:\Desktop` instead of `C:\Desktop\hello`.

Comment: You should use something like [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) for searching through a directory.

Comment: @idjaw I can't use os.walk nor glob for this unfortunately.

Comment: `interesting[0]` is using the wrong variable the split variable is `interesting1`.

Comment: @AChampion I changed interesting[0] to interesting1[0], but it's still producing the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this should work.

```
def search_characteristics(directory):
    interesting = input()
    interesting = interesting.split(" ")
    if (interesting[0] == 'N'):
        directory += (os.sep + interesting[1])
        print(directory)
    elif interesting.startswith('E'):
        return os.path.splitext(directory,'')
    else:
        print("Error")
        return search_characteristics(directory)
```

If you have to use os.path.join then you can replace the line with os.sep with:

```
directory = os.path.join(directory, interesting[1])
```

Comment: I edited my original post as I got it to work, but ran into another problem. If I were to put `N hello` , it would show up as `C:\Desktop\hello' but what if the file doesnt exist say `N doesntexist` which I would need to check if it were a file. I added the if isfile to check if it is a file, but no matter what I do, it would say `Not a file` even if it were a file.

Comment: I tried running your code and I had no issues. What are you using for your inputs?

Comment: The code works fine, but I feel it's working in the wrong way. I feel it might be getting the "Not a file" input I put in because it's not really a file, but a directory. Basically  say I have a real file named `realfile.txt` and a file named fakefile that doesn't exist. 

I would run the code. `C:\Desktop` I would input in N realfile.txt and it would return `C:\Desktop\reaifile.txt`. I run it again and put N fakefile.txt. It should say "Not a file". When I run my current code, I get "Not a file" for both. How would I fix it so the real file doesn't give "not a file" error?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I checked it with a real file and a fake one and it gave the correct response in both cases. You are correct in that os.path.isfile() would return false if the entry was a directory, but as I said I don't see how your getting the directory.

Comment: What are you using for the directory or what are your inputs? I'm getting the directory from the `if __name__ == '__main__'.

Comment: I was using Desktop as well. My inputs are as follows: "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop" and then "test.py".

Comment: Did you input a N as well?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The second input was "N test.py"

Comment: Are you running it with the code I have on the top of the thread or did you take out the isfile()?

Comment: I just copied what is in your question verbatim. So the code I am running is what is currently in the question.

Comment: Hm I'm getting "Not a file" with the code I'm using with the thread.

Comment: I should note that I am using python2.7. I see that you marked it with python3.x so I don't know if that is having an affect.

Comment: Oh I fixed it. I'm sure I look dumb with finding out what the problem is now.. I was testing the code with a downloaded text file I had to use back a while ago called gutenberg. I kept typing gutenburg which was why I kept getting "Not a file". haha